# How to directly import nested item in Python?

Tags: python, python-import

Let's say i have a `src` folder with `Player.py` file, that has class `PlayVideo` in it. Can I directly import that class from `main.py` file that is in same folder as `src`?

Normally, to use that class I would do

```
from src import Player
    
Player.PlayVideo("videofile.mp4")
```

Is it possible to directly import the `PlayVideo` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as `Player` is a Python file (`.py`) or Python module (directory containing an `__init__.py` file), you can do:

```
from src.Player import PlayVideo
```

See the docs on importing submodules here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: It seems to work only with Python 3, Python 2.7.15 returns ImportError. Is there a way to do that in Python 2 as well?

Comment: Scratch that, Python 2 just needs `__init__.py` file as well. Python 3 works works even without it. Thanks!

Comment: @w1kl4s right, including an `__init__.py` file in a directory makes the directory into a Python module. Glad that worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The previous is an extremely common import. I'd guess your answer would be:

```
import src.Player.PlayVideo as PlayVideo
```

It works for something like:

```
import statsmodels.regression.linear_model as line
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You don't need to import the object `as` the same name, you can simply use `from <library>.<module> import <thing>`. You could do the same with `plt` e.g. by doing `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`.